# I can't render on blender using a GPU on mac

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

Whenever I try to render on my GPU it says:

OpenCL build failed: errors in console

**Here is my Computer Specifications:**

- macbook pro mid 2014
- i7 2.5Ghz CPU
- Nvidia GT750m
- OSX 10.11.2 / El Capitan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macbook Pro sometimes have 2 graphic card available for it's system. An intergrated one and a standalone GPU. Make sure the GT750m is selected in
your user preference with CUDA turn on.

[image]

Comment: yeah i already did that and it does not work and also mine does not say cuda it says openGL for some reason

Comment: I have check that GT750m does support CUDA, however I am not sure if CUDA would work on a mac OSX environment you will have to check with machintosh side of things. If you cannot access the CUDA portion ... I fear you might have issue using it. You may even have to manually download a MacOSX version CUDA toolkit to solve the problem.

Comment: ok i checked it turns out can get cuda on mac in nvidia develeoper zone part of their website thing let me go try that thx

Comment: some additional info here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92264/cycles-render-on-gt750-gpu-macbook-pro-2gb-graphics-2-79-blender/101200#101200