# Cycles Render on GT750 GPU (MacBook Pro) 2GB Graphics - 2.79 Blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, osx

I have a GT750 Graphics Chip in my MacBook Pro, it has 2GB of dedicated VRAM, I would like to use this to render rather than the CPU.

The MacBook also has a Quad Core i7 2.6GHz and is able to render using the cycles engine perfectly, however looking at benchmarks even though the GT750 is not a hugely powerful chip, it should still perform better than the CPU.

I have gone onto NVIDIAs site and downloaded and installed the latest CUDA Drivers, and then restarted my Mac. I then went into 'User Preferences -> System' and only OpenCL is available, there is not a option for CUDA. Please see the screenshot.

If I go ahead and use GPU / cycles rendering on OpenCL the application just quits without any errors shown.

This is using Blender 2.79

Thank you for any help

[image]

Comment: Make sure you download the correct CUDA driver: http://www.nvidia.com/object/mac-driver-archive.html The new ones recommends cuda compute capability 8.0, while the GT750 only supports 3.0. I am unsure if that matters on Mac. Also make sure in your Energy System Preferences the "Automatic Graphics Switching" is disabled.

Answer (score 3):

OpenCL does not work (yet?) for Blender on MBP with NVidia. It worked with CUDA for me on mid 2014 MBP with GT750M 2GB Nvidia but I had to install the latest NVidia drivers and CUDA, however the result was extremely disappointing, pretty much the equivalent of single core CPU rendering instead of 8-core! Don't waste your time with this with the GT750M.

Since the NVidia GEForce drivers are not stamped by Apple, they are hard to find even on the NVidia website. I used this site as source of the NVidia link! https://www.tonymacx86.com/forums/graphics.13/

At the time of this post, the latest drivers are http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/130460/en-us

... which also includes the link to download CUDA...